# Slight difference between SVG and canvas when rendering text (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, svg, canvas, text

I'm converting a SVG text to a canvas rendering but noticed a slight difference when comparing the two texts (only on Chrome)

Here's a sample code that I used to make the conversion

```
// this svg code is normally calculated dynamically
var svg_code = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -272 501 336" width="501" height="336">
    <text font-size="300" font-family="'Arial'" fill="#f00" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle">
        <tspan x="50%" dy="0">123</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>`;

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = svg_code;


var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, " + 
    encodeURIComponent(svg_code.replace('fill="#f00"', 'fill="#0f0"'));

img.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = "canvas";
  canvas.width = 501;
  canvas.height = 336;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(canvas);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/unloco/51ntyLps/68/)

Here's a screenshot showing the slight different between the red text (SVG) and the green text (canvas)

[image: Difference between svg and canvas text]

It's not much, but I'm using the image to trim the SVG text so it has to be pixel perfect

Here's another [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/unloco/51ntyLps/67/) using another font

How to fix this difference or how to avoid it?

**Info**:
This is caused by the canvas hardware acceleration ("Accelerated 2D canvas" Chrome flag)

Chrome bug
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1037834

Comment: Text rendering is a very complicated beast, and you will have different results on every systems. Simply moving that jsfiddle from a  2DPR monitor to a 1DPR one changes the output on my macOs computer, and I'm sure it's still very different than what windows' ClearType will produce.

Comment: I only expected that SVG and Canvas would match. On Firefox, it's perfect, I'll submit it to the Chrome tracker and see how it goes. I found no other way to "trim" the SVG text so this is my only chance!

Comment: The thing is as svg in the doc, your text is part of the DOM and can be composited with the rest of the page, even if the background changes, they can thus use something like subpixel rendering there, while when it's painted on the canvas, the pixels are fixed, they need to use some alpha blending antialiasing. I'm not sure they'll see it as a bug, since it's for better in case of SVG, and I wouldn't expect FF behavior to never change either.

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido, I tried changing font smoothing but it didn't make a difference. I disabled "Accelerated 2D canvas" in Chrome flags and it did solve the problem although I can't ask users to switch a flag.